# Zend Frameworks "Enable Layout" Error

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have seen a few posts regarding this issue, but still am having trouble. 
I am new to zf and when I am trying to enable layout using:  zf enable layout 
I get an error showing: 
***An Error Has Occured 
A Project File was not found. 
Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.12.8 
Details for action "Enable" and provider "Layout" 
  Layout 
   zf enable layout.***

I have read that I might be missing the .zfproject.xml but if I am, I am not sure where to look or how to add it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a newby when it comes to PHP and zf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set two paths to make zf tool work:

### First Step

For Windows

Right Click on My Computer and Click on Properties. Now add the zf tool path like this:

[image]

### Second Step

Open Your php.ini file and add zend library path so you can use zf tool from anywhere:

[image]

I hope your problem of enable layout will solve after this.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It WORKED.  I am not sure how I missed that before.